# multiple of a crossed homomorphism from finite group to a divisible one is principal

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory, abelian-groups, galois-cohomology

Let $\pi$
  be a finite group, $\left|\pi\right|=n$
 , acting on an abelian, torsion-free, $n$
 -divisible group $D$
  (i.e., every element of $D$
  is divisible by $n$
 ). Consider a crossed homomorphism $f:\,\pi\rightarrow D$
  (i.e., a function such that $f\left(\sigma\tau\right)=f\left(\sigma\right)^{\tau}+f\left(\tau\right)$
  for every $\sigma,\tau\in\pi$
 , where $\tau$
  acts on $f\left(\sigma\right)$
 ). Is it true that $nf$
  is a principal homomorphism? Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

Comment: What do you conjecture? Is it? Did you try out any examples? Did you try proving it? Please share your thoughts with us first.

Comment: I want to prove that $nf$
  is a principal homomorphism. It seems to me that you cannot prove it directly, but using in some way the correspondence between conjugacy classes of complements of $D$
  in the semidirect product $\pi\times_{\varphi}D$
  ($\varphi$
  is the action of $\pi$
  on $D$
 ) and $H^{1}\left(\pi,D\right)$
 . I suppose that the fundamental hypothesis is the finiteness of the group $\pi$
 , but I can be wrong.

Comment: It is known that for any finite group G and any G-module M, the cohomology groups H^i (G, M) , for i > 0, are killed by the order of G. This is a consequence of the properties of the maps Res and Cores. See e.g. Serre's "Local Fields", chapter VIII, coroll. 1 of propos. 4.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this question was already asked in mathstack exchange. The answer is here [first homology group with coefficients in divisible group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784551/first-homology-group-with-coefficients-in-divisible-group?rq=1)

Comment: Okay. You could upvote that answer (and question too, maybe) if it was helpful to you.